# Unet with structured data

Tags: python, csv, deep-learning

Has there been any exploration or experimentation with the application of UNet, typically used for image segmentation tasks, on structured data (CSV) for classification purposes? Specifically, I'm referring to a dataset containing 36 features where the objective is classification. I'm curious if UNet has been utilized or considered in such scenarios.

I am tried to train Unet on structured data (1-D), I have to reshape the data to have shape that resembles an image like format, as 6*6 grid for 36 features. I am working on this now, I am not sure if the Unet can predict patterns from this data as do with images.

Do you think I can have a high accuracy with Unet, similar to what I got when I trained my data on machine learning model?

Comment: I dont think Unet is a suitable network for this task.